# How can I extract frames from GIF animation image on Gimp

Tags: gimp

I would like to know if there are any scripts or plugins on Gimp to extract frames from a GIF animation image as individually PNG images.

I recently switched to Ubuntu 12.04 from windows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this by using a shell script that comes with `Ubuntu tweak-tool`

If you already have Ubuntu tweak installed then open it and goto

`Admins tab>>Personal>>scripts`

[image: s1]

and drag drop the `convert image to PNG` to the left under enabled scripts.

[image: s2]

Once thats done right click on a GIF image and goto `scripts>>convert image to PNG`

And in a few secs you will have all the frames extracted in the same folder.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! it works perfectly and I don't even have to use Gimp.